# send textbox array values throgh Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

im trying to submit form throgh ajax. my form contain two textbox with same name to get it as an array value.
im trying to send this array textbox values with Ajax.
the code i have tried is given below.

**form**

```
<input name="name"  value="name"/>
<input name="email[]"  value="one@gmail.com"/>
<input name="email[]"  value="two@gmail.com"/>
<input name="msg"  value="message"/>
```

**Ajax script**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "sendmail.php",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            name: $('#ame').val(),
            email: $('[name="email[]"]').serialize(),
            msg: $('#msg').val()

        },
```

**sendmail.php**

```
$c_email = $_POST['email'];
foreach ( $c_emails as $cmail) {
echo $cmail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
email : $('[name="email[]"]').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and you will get all data of the form on next php script.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "sendmail.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
```

In your PHP code

```
<?php
   $emails = $_POST['email'];
   foreach($emails as $email) {
       echo $email;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can be a bit picky about quotes.  This will build the string you are looking for:

```
$("div#result").html($("input[name='email[]']").serialize());
```

This returns the empty string:

```
$("div#result").html($('input[name="email[]"]').serialize());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5v69bx4/